# diagnose broken peripheric via android (for example... detect damaged bluetooth)

Tags: android, bluetooth, hardware, wifi

Im searching for a opportunity to get feedback, if a mobile phone component is working or damaged. Is there any special feature?

Example: I want to enable Bluetooth sensor via java code, but the Bluetoothsensor is damaged. Any Exception or so?

Answer (score 0):

probably, the device, not informs you, that is damaged.

If you try to access to the bluetooth and  the bluetooth is damaged, you cannot get any features of it, and you get an error but not an error something like "Bluetooth damaged". Check the bluetooth documentation for the kinds of errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to see advanced hardware stats (like RAM clock and voltage) and perform health tests (like low-level SD read-write tests) - the most sure-fire way to do that is to use native code to make system calls. But many calls will require the device to be rooted

Generally, Android API will just give you availability of hardware, like so (taken [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/nfc.html)):

```
// Check for available NFC Adapter
mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
if (mNfcAdapter == null) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "NFC is not available", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

But you can't interpret this as malfunction or anything. I don't know of any part of Android Java API that's officially meant to diagnose hardware malfunctions.

You can get [Android source code](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html) and see what NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter() does to give you an idea on how *hardware* you can get with Java API.